# Laravel Substract two withSums

Tags: laravel

```
$titles = Title::withSum('solds', 'quantity')->withSum('purchases', 'quantity')->paginate(20);
```

How to substract in query (purchases_sum_quantity - solds_sum_quantity)

I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To subtract the sum of solds from the sum of purchases, you can use the selectRaw method in your query to calculate the difference. Here's an example:

```
 $titles = Title::withSum('solds', 'quantity')
                ->withSum('purchases', 'quantity')
                ->selectRaw('SUM(purchases.quantity) - SUM(solds.quantity) as net_quantity')
                ->paginate(20);
```

In this query, the selectRaw method is being used to calculate the difference between the sum of purchases.quantity and the sum of solds.quantity and give it the alias net_quantity. This will add a new field to the result set that contains the calculated value for each row.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'purchases.quantity' in 'field list'